# How to access a Class from another

Tags: c#, oop

I know how to create an instance of a class etc. But for some reason I cannot create an instance of the class I want because it does not detect that the class is even there.

I am using visual Studio and writing my code in C#. Please help me. I want to access the watcher class inside of the Program class.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {

  public Program()
    {
    }

    // DOWNLOAD
    private void Download(string filePath, string fileName)
    {
        // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://50.62.234.1");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

        // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test", "test");

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

        Console.WriteLine("Download Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
    }

    private void Upload (string filePath, string fileName)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://something.com");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    }

    private void ListDirectoryItems()
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://something.com");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test", "test");

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

        Console.WriteLine("Directory List Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // List contents of FTP Directory
        Program program = new Program();
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading..... Please wait....");
        // List contents of FTP Directory
        program.ListDirectoryItems();
        // if there is items in the directory download those items
        program.Download("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm", "test.htm");
        Console.WriteLine("File Downloaded");

    }
}
}

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class Watcher
    {
    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public static void Run()
    {
        string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

        // if the directory is not specified, exit the program
        if (args.Length != 2)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Usage: Watcher.exe (directory)");
            return;
        }

        // Create the file watcher and set its properties
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = args[1];

        // Watch for changes
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

        // only watch text files for now.
        watcher.Filter = ".txt";

        // Event handlers
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Renamed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

        // Begin watching
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        // Wait for users to quit the program
        Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
        while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
    }

    // Define the event handlers
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
        Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
    }

    private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
        Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your class only has static methods. No need to create an instance. Just use 

     Watcher.Run();

Comment: Intel-sense cant find Watcher from the Program class, are you sure?

Comment: Does your code compile ?
Is your class in the same folder as the main class ?

Comment: It does compile and the classes are both in the same folder.

Comment: watcher.Renamed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler' to 'System.IO.RenamedEventHandler'

I think it should say watcher.Renamed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnRenamed); instead

Comment: It errors but it does compile and you can compile into an executable. Either way I should be able to access the Watcher class either way,

Comment: If you get an error, it wont compile. The executable you have might be an old one. Try to Clean the project and build again

Comment: Oka y thank you, and the program crashes because the ftp server is down. That is not my problem though. I just want to be able to access the Run method inside Watcher inside the program class.

Comment: If the watcher class has an error, the it wont show up in intellisence, you have to clear out all errors.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead for your watcher class..

It compiles and it show up in intellisence

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
public class Watcher
{
    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public static void Run()
    {
        string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

        // if the directory is not specified, exit the program
        if (args.Length != 2)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Usage: Watcher.exe (directory)");
            return;
        }

        // Create the file watcher and set its properties
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = args[1];

        // Watch for changes
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

        // only watch text files for now.
        watcher.Filter = ".txt";

        // Event handlers
        watcher.Changed += Watcher_Changed;
        watcher.Created += Watcher_Changed;
        watcher.Deleted += Watcher_Changed;
        watcher.Renamed += Watcher_Renamed;

        // Begin watching
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        // Wait for users to quit the program
        Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
        while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
    }

    private static void Watcher_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
    }

    private static void Watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you but, is it showing up in your program cs file? Still no go for me.

Comment: Try putting your namespace.